# sfguard bundle for symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, propel, sfguard

There is a bundle for ([Propel](https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle)) for symfony2,is there sfguard bundle for symfony2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no sfGuard bundle (yet), but have you checked out [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)? I actually like it better than sfGuard.

Answer (score 2):

The [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) does the job and it's fully compatible with Propel. Note the official bundle for Propel is the [PropelBundle](https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle).

William

Answer (score 1):

sfGuard Bundle for symfony2 is not available yet.

Comment: And it won't ever be. FOSUserBundle is its successor.

Answer (score 1):

FOSUserBundle is better than sfGuardUser, it allow to use different data source as ORM (Doctrine), MongoDB/CouchDB ODM or Propel.

Out of the box this Bundle does NOT support database persisted roles, the ACL functionality is allow but only on two level of user: ROLE_USER, and ROLE_ADMIN, this roles can be grant to the user by the command line.

```
$ php app/console fos:user:promote testuser ROLE_ADMIN
```

You can found more about how store role on the data source at this link http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/symfony2-fosuserbundle-roles